# What is the difference between using namespace A and using A::a and how does it affect the scope?

Tags: c++, c++17

I have a code snippet:

```
namespace Work {
 void catch_mouse(); 
}

namespace Tom {
 using namespace Work;
 void catch_mouse();
}

int main() {
 Tom::catch_mouse();
}
```

The above code works and calls `Tom::catch_mouse();`

But the same code with using declaration produces an error.

```
namespace Work {
 void catch_mouse(); 
}

namespace Tom {
 using Work::catch_mouse;
 void catch_mouse(); // gives an error; conflicting declaration of catch_mouse
}

int main() {
 Tom::catch_mouse();
}
```

As I understand, both `using namespace Work` and `using Work::catch_mouse` brings the declaration into scope then why the first one compiles and the second one produces error?

Comment: The first imports the entire namespace `A`; the second only imports `A::a`. Surely this is obvious?

Comment: @user207421 But it doesn't explain why name lookup behaves differently between the two.

Answer (score 4):

There is a subtle difference. A [using directive](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace#Using-directives)  like

```
using namespace Work;
```

means that

> From the point of view of unqualified name lookup of any name after a
> using-directive and until the end of the scope in which it appears,
> every name from namespace-name is visible as if it were declared in
> the nearest enclosing namespace which contains both the
> using-directive and namespace-name.

This means that, when the compilers searches `catch_mouse`, it will also find it inside the `Work` namespace. Specifically, in [unqualified name lookup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/unqualified_lookup):

> For an unqualified name, that is a name that does not appear to the
> right of a scope resolution operator ::, name lookup examines the
> scopes as described below, until it finds at least one declaration of
> any kind, at which time the lookup stops and no further scopes are
> examined.

In your first case, the compiler will first find the `catch_mouse()` explicitly declared inside `Tom` namespace *and then stops the search*.
You can convince yourself that this is the case by examining the output of this code:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace Work {
 void catch_mouse() { std::cout << "this is work" << std::endl; } 
}

namespace Tom {
 using namespace Work;
 void catch_mouse() { std::cout << "this is tom" << std::endl; }
}

int main() {
 Tom::catch_mouse();
}
```

See it [live on  Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6153393633d61bd3).

The program prints "this is tom" because the compiler has found the `catch_mouse` in Tom.

Your second case

```
using Work::catch_mouse;
```

is a [using declaration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace#Using-declarations), which (emphasis mine)

> makes the symbol member-name from the namespace ns-name accessible for
> unqualified lookup **as if declared in the same class scope, block
> scope, or namespace** as where this using-declaration appears.

This means that you explicitly tell the compiler to "import" the declaration of the `Work::catch_mouse` inside the current Tom namespace, as if it were declared here.
But then you have conflicting declaration of `catch_mouse`: should the compiler consider inside `namespace Tom` the declaration of `Work::catch_mouse` or of `Tom::catch_mouse`?
This would also leads an ambiguity: when you call `catch_mouse()`, should the compiler pick up the `Work` or the `Tom` versions? Unlike the first case, both declarations of `catch_mouse` are on equal footing now.
This is why the code does not compile.

Comment: +1, but I believe _a duplicated declaration of catch_mouse, hence the code does not compile_ has to be reworded, because _**duplicate**_ declarations are just fine (try writing `void catch_mouse(); void catch_mouse();` will work just fine); **_conficting_** declarations are the problem.

Comment: The conflicting declarations are not only an issue for overload resolution. Even if there was no call, introducing a conflicting declaration via a `using` declaration makes the program ill-formed. However, this doesn't apply to the `using namespace` directive.

Answer (score 0):

the reason for this behavior is that using a namespace really lets you use the namespace's members without the explicit ::, but using namespace::member is different! it serves as a declaration and is actually called 'using-declarations'.
therefor the above code actually declares two functions of the same name and type which leads to the conflicting declaration error.

you can read more about it here under 'using-declarations':
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace